# Choose function return 2 columns on Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

Is there any way to return the two columns in the choose function

For example, here in excel (image), I can do it with:

```
=CHOOSE({1\2};B1:B10;A1:A10)
```

[formula in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIsZD.png)

**Is there a way to do this in google sheets? Or some similar formula?**

Comment: hi, you again <3

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nXsVLJlDD9i-63cyHHQk8icFW138A5otfrqS0MyjpAs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: actually, I wanted this formula to be able to do a "procv"...

I wanted the columns (cod 2, produto, data,  tipo) based on I and J, but with proc it won't

any suggestion

Comment: can you edit your sheet and include example of desired output you need to achieve?

Comment: I wanted a formula that me the column F, A, B, C, D and E, in that order (can't be through the query function)

I put an example in the worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={C1:C11\ A1:A11}
```

or if your sheet is english:

```
={C1:C11, A1:A11}
```

---

### update:

```
={F1:F12, A1:E12}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what happens, but it doesn't return as an array (table) but in a single column (one under the other) :c

Comment: @melo answer updated. see your sheet. cell A30